# Embed a Tweet in Ionic App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, twitter

I'm currently creating a sports news application by retrieving data via my JSON API and in this data I get the HTML part of a tweet when there are tweets in my articles.

```
<blockquote> ... </ blockquote>
```

After doing some research on the internet, I integrated the Twitter script in index.html, but my tweets are not displayed entirely, I think the Javascript part is not called ..

index.html :

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

contenu-article.html :

```
<div [innerHTML]="tweet | keepHtml" *ngIf="tweet">{{tweet}}</div>
```

Comment: No one to help me ? :/

Comment: did u find a solution my friend